# Turn off visual studio code inline parent/child folder display

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im not sure if this is an extension or an update but ever since the most recent VS code update they have single folders inline with parent folders. I didnt think it would bother me as much but I find that is driving me crazy, I much to prefer to just have child folders nested underneath the first time instead of dynamically changing all the time based on my folder structure.

Here is an image example, anybody know what this setting is called?

[image]

Answer (score 317, accepted):

`File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Features -> Explorer` and untick the compact folders checkbox.

Or directly in your `settings.json`, add `"explorer.compactFolders": false`.

Comment: To reach settings.json, use Ctrl+Shift+P to open the command palette, then type "settings.json" and hit enter (the item is called "Preferences: Open Settings")

Comment: I really dislike this feature. Surprising that anyone would want this on by default.